# nginx cache control not working even with the config

Tags: nginx, cache-control

I'm using webpagetest and pagespeed for optimisation. But both are saying that no cache control has been implemented even though I have it in the config.

config below:

```
server {
        #listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/public;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name thewebsite.com; # managed by Certbot

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|webp)$ {
            expires 1M;
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2629746, public";
        }


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location = /livewire/livewire.js {
            expires off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        
       location /nginx_status {
          stub_status on;
          access_log   off;
          allow 127.0.0.1;
          deny all;
        }
}

# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    epoch;
}

server {    
    location /nginx_status {
          stub_status on;
          access_log   off;
          allow 127.0.0.1;
          deny all;
        }

        listen 80 ;
        server_name thewebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    expires $expires;
}
```

Comment: is the website a secret or the actual domain?

Comment: @djdomi a secret

Comment: @djdomi I doubt that whoever owns that domain would be posting on here lol.

Answer (score 0):

I am doubtful about *1M*. please try *30d* instead of *1M* and change *add_header* line to this. also *Pragma* provides cached header to old clients and some online tools may consider them:

```
expires 30d;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
```

Comment: thanks! will give this a try